# What is the difference between Control.FindForm and ContainerControl.ParentForm

Tags: .net, windows, winforms

I'm wondering if there is any functional (or otherwise) difference between `Control.FindForm` and `ContainerControl.ParentForm`?  I've been using `.ParentForm` when creating my own user controls but would there be any reason `.FindForm` would be a better choice?  From what I can tell, they would always return the same form (ie. the form the user control is on, or null).  Is `.ParentForm` just calling `.FindForm` or is there a time where the two could be different (maybe with mdi windows)?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

They are subtly different.  ParentForm will return null when you call it on a toplevel Form since it has no parent.  FindForm() will not, it returns itself.  And ParentForm makes a security demand, FindForm() does not.  They otherwise use the same internal implementation.  Winforms itself doesn't use ParentForm at all, I would ignore it.

Comment: Ok, thanks.  Can you explain a bit more about what is meant by a security demand of ParentForm? Or point me somewhere for reference?

Comment: CodeAccessPermission class.  Winforms allows sandboxing a control so it cannot tinker with its parent.  This is not otherwise well documented.  Or relevant in 99.9% of all Winforms projects.