# How to access parent form?

Tags: c#, winforms

Ok, so a lot of people have asked this question in one way or another, but there doesn't seem to be many answers out there apart from pass the parent object when calling the child. The problem is, I do not have access to the parent code.

Here is my situation.

Some code I have no access to, I just have use of the dll(the parent form), calls a function in my code (the child form).

My function makes a call to a 3rd party SDK(not so important) which needs the parent form as one of the parameters. Also, I have no access to the 3rd party code, only through some c++ libraries.

Can my child form ever know its parent, or is it doomed to be an orphan?

Comment: Is `ParentForm` property not working for you?

Comment: Or how about [`FindForm()`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6793707)?

Comment: What do you mean exactly by `Parent form`? If your child form has a parent, the parent form will contain it, that means the child form can't be moved out of the `Bounds` of the `Parent form`. I think you mean the `Owner form`.

Comment: @KingKing Has a good point. Is it the form's container that you are after, or the owner form (which will be a different window, and which will always be displayed BEHIND the owned form)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In *the most general case* (since your form is somewhere in dll and you have to pass the parent form into 3rd party software) - WinAPI - you can retrieve the parent window handle with `GetParent` function

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633510(v=vs.85).aspx

Something like that:

```
[DllImport("user32.dll",
           EntryPoint = "GetParent",
           CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
internal static extern IntPtr GetParent(IntPtr hWnd); 

...

IntPtr parentHandle = GetParent(myForm.Handle); // <- If you have a form

...

IntPtr myFormHandle = ...
IntPtr myFormParentHandle = GetParent(myFormHandle); // <- If you have WHND only

// If there's a .net form with myFormParentHandle Handle you can retrieve it 
// Otherwise (e.g. form is not a .net one) you get null
Form parentForm = Control.FromHandle(myFormParentHandle) as Form;
```

Comment: this looks like it could be the ticket. Is it possible to convert this intptr back to its object? ie, will I be able to get the parent Form?

Comment: @user1934821 Yes `Form parent = (Form)Control.FromHandle(parentHandle)`

Answer (score 2):

Maybe I'm missing something, but you can just use [`ContainerControl.ParentForm`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.containercontrol.parentform.aspx)

```
var parent = myForm.ParentForm;
```

Or (if you don't actually have a Form to interrogate, but have a Control instead):

```
var parent = myForm.Parent;
```

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.parent.aspx

Then the Windows API handle for that parent will be:

```
IntPtr handle = parent.Handle;
```

which you can pass to your 3rd party SDK.

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.handle.aspx

If you need to check that the parent is really a Form:

```
Form form = myForm.Parent as Form;

if (form != null)
    // Do something with form.
```

But like people said: You should just be able to use `myForm.ParentForm`

Comment: Form's `Parent` or `ParentForm` is useless when `TopLevel` is true. by default `TopLevel` is true. I think you mean `Owner`

Comment: [Hans Passant recommends to _not_ use `ParentForm` but `FindForm()` instead](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6794596/107625).

Comment: @SriramSakthivel OP was asking for parent form rather than owner, though?

Comment: Can you elaborate what is parent form? How it is parented? question is unclear for me though. `Parent Form` makes no sense unclear. It makes sense for `MDIParent` Am I missing something?

Comment: @UweKeim The security demand differences are not important. The main difference is that `FindForm()` does NOT return null when the form has no parent. If you need to know that the form has no parent, you should call `ParentForm`, NOT `FindForm()`.

Comment: @SriramSakthivel The parent is the container control which contains the form or control. The owner is such that when a form is owned by another form, it is closed or hidden with the owner form.

Comment: Partially correct. A form cannot parent another unless you use `SetParent` api or `TopMost` set to false. When used `SetParent` `Parent` property will return null(but not sure). To prove `Form f = new Form();f.Parent = this;f.Show();` this will throw `ArgumentException`

Answer (score 0):

Does your form appear over the top of another? Try the [Form.Owner](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.owner.aspx) property.

Are you absolutely sure that you want to do this? There may be a good reason that you are not given the opportunity to access the parent form. Take care that you do not break the framework or pattern by circumventing this restriction.

Comment: yes, the disadvantage of integrating one legacy system with another. :(

Answer (score 0):

It's better (for your mental sanity) to pass from the parent form all needed information to the child's forms so you only have to think in one way (parent form pass some information to the child, the child pass the information + more information to the next child and so on)

Do a form/class that depends of other forms is called hard coupling and its a problem to maintain software.

Comment: this is not an option because I have no access to the parent code